# CoreData batch insert Entities with Relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

Is there anyway to insert entities with relationship? I get error "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'content' between objects in different contexts"

```
addUsers(users: [userData])
```

```
func addUsers(users: [User]) {
    
    let taskContext = container.viewContext
    
    taskContext.perform {
        let batchInsertRequest = self.newBatchInsertRequest(with: users)
        if let fetchResult = try? taskContext.execute(batchInsertRequest),
           let batchInsertResult = fetchResult as? NSBatchInsertResult,
           let success = batchInsertResult.result as? Bool, success {
            return
        }
    }
    
}
```

crash happens in below code

```
private func newBatchInsertRequest(with users: [Users]) -> NSBatchInsertRequest {
        var index = 0
        let total = message.count
        
        
        let batchInsertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: WaUser.entity(), managedObjectHandler: { managedObject in
            guard index < total else { return true }
            
            let user = users[index]
            
            
            if let waUser = managedObject as? WaUser {
                waUser.name = user.name

                let waUserInfo = waUserInfo(context: self.container.viewContext)
                waUserInfo.pass = "12345"
                waUserInfo.key = "asdfgh"

                waUser.info = waUserInfo **//crash occurs here**
               
            }
            
            index += 1
            return false
        })
        
        return batchInsertRequest
   }
```

Comment: And how do you use the result of this function, please share the code where the request is executed

Comment: Hello @JoakimDanielson, I added the code you mention

Comment: After reading up on this I believe you can't do this when using batch insert so you need to create and assign your waUserInfo afterwards